# Can I use Xbox 360 controllers with Xbox Classic (first generation of Xbox)?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, xbox

This is a tricky question and I can't find reliable answer anywhere on the Internet.

I love my old [Xbox Classic (the first Xbox console from 2001)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_(console)). Unfortunately both my original pads have died, then I got replacements, but they're almost done too.

I'm wondering if it's possible to use my Xbox 360 (wired because I guess wireless is impossible?) pads with the first generation of Xbox consoles?

All I could find was [this](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/can-you-use-a-wired-xbox360-controller-on-the-original-xbox-138369/), but it explains almost nothing. I guess I will need adapters from USB to "proprietary USB interface" of the Xbox, but where do I get one? And if I get these adapters will they support the Xbox 360 fully, will I be able to play games just fine?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: When you say your controllers "died", what do you mean exactly? Are certain buttons not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching around, I don't see any kind of adapter for an Xbox 360 controller to an Xbox port.  I don't think the original Xbox supported any wireless controller either.  The Original Xbox certainly had some sort of proprietary port for it's controllers, but I've read that it's just a standard USB in a weird form factor.  Third party modifications may be possible, but would be quite a hassle to try.

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_controller) for the Original Xbox controller:

> Neither the original Xbox controller nor Controller S are compatible with the Xbox 360, **and the Xbox 360 controller is not compatible with an original Xbox.**

I think one of the biggest problems between the platforms is the software used to interpret the inputs of the controllers.  The Xbox 360 controller uses the [XInput API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417014(v=vs.85).aspx), while the original Xbox's controller likely used something else (it's not mentioned on the webpage for XInput anywhere), meaning even if you were able to somehow get an Xbox 360 controller to connect to an Original Xbox, it probably wouldn't be able to read any input.

Answer (score 0):

XBOX 360 Controller to Mayflash Universal Ultimate Adapter (XB018) to Brook Super Converter(bluetooth/usb) PS3/PS4 to PS2/PS1 Adapter to Game Elements PS2 to Original Xbox Converter.

According to Mayflash the XB018 Adapter doesn't work with a Microsoft Receiver so wired only, but could try.

The PS3 & PS4 wireless controllers do work fine on the Original Xbox (incl. rumble)

Answer (score 0):

### Plug and Play

Brook makes an adapter called [Wingman XB](https://www.brookaccessory.com/detail/59327520/) for connecting different types of controllers to an Original Xbox, including the 360 and One/Series controllers.

### DIY

There is now a Free and Open Source project called [ogx360](https://github.com/Ryzee119/ogx360), which aims to make the Xbox 360 controller work with the Original Xbox. It also works with One/Series controllers.

You would need to build your own adapter, which requires learning how to solder. If you have the skills to do this, it's the cheaper option, going for around 30 USD for the parts.